# Прозрачность в background-color при наложении нескольких элементов

Tags: html, css, opacity

Имеется структура

```
<div style="width:1517px; height:81px; position:relative;">
    <div class="gray_section" style="height: 80px; left: 0px; width: 493px; top: 0px;"></div>
    <div class="gray_section" style="height: 80px; left: 410px; width: 207px; top: 0px;"></div>
</div>
```

Эту структуру генерирует `js` код, достаточно сложный для изменения.
Класс `gray_section` имеет следующее значение:

```
<style>
.gray_section {
    background-color: rgba(118, 108, 119, 0.5) !important;
}
</style>
```

Учитывая `left` и `width` у элементов с классом `gray_section`, некоторые участки пересекаются и там где это происходит, прозрачность "суммируется" и эти области получаются уже имеют другой оттенок. Как можно от этого избавиться? То есть что бы прозрачность не суммировалась.

Для более наглядного обзора: стрелкой показана область пересечения, где "суммируется" прозрачность.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]